# Something similar to the description environment

Tags: description

I have found this in a paper:

[image: example]

It seems very similar to the description environment, but I don't know which environment it could be or how to search for it. Do someone of you know it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You could achieve this (somehow) with a `\paragraph` command, but does it look preferable at all? No, not in my opinion

Comment: Hi and welcome, right now, this lookos just like `\large\sffamily` text. Nothing special about it. I wouldn't recomend to do it though.

Comment: you could set up a list env, but I suspect it was just `\textsf{Direct..}`

Comment: It might be obtained as `run-in`  style, unnumbered `\paragraph`, easy to obtain with `titlesec`.